# how to check username and password from my own table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net webforms we can determine members or admins table for login like :

```
select * from tbladmins where username = @p1 and password = @p2
```

but in asp.net mvc it has own database , table and class .. Membership class connect to own table for check username and password ..

I want to know how can I use Membership class for my own admins table ?! I mean I want to check my own table on my own database by Membership class . but Membership use asp.net database on local server for checking username and password . by this way every site need 2 database for Account and other data like posts , news and etc ..

I have a table with this columns : `id , username , password` .

How can I check this table by `Membership` class ?

Comment: You need to write your own `MembershipProvider` that will read your own table (instead of using the ASP.NET default tables) - and it's really not that big a deal - check out [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Comment: How can I read my own table ?! I want to know this .. how ?! How can I read my own table ?

Comment: See my comment - you need to **write some code** for your own custom membership provider, and then install that provider into ASP.NET

Comment: @marc_s : do you have any sample code ?

Comment: [See this video example - including sample code!](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

Comment: Skip the Membership Provider, get a good ORM such as Entity Framework or Nhibernate, use a one way hash for passwords. The ASP.NET Membership Providers are old and lousy

Comment: @CrazyCoderz : I used Entity Framework before but in this ORM I can't create login form with my own table .. do you have any sample code for Entity Framework ?

Comment: @CrazyCoderz : I red this article and it's very good .. but I want to have my own fields .. http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.in/2012/04/membership-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html